# Django OperationalError no such table

Tags: django

I'm making a sign up page.
html

```html
{{message}}
<form action="{% url 'signup' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" autofocus type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="confirmation" placeholder="Confirm Password">
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

django

```py
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        confirmation = request.POST['confirmation']

        if password != confirmation:
            return render(request, 'lms/signup.html', {
                'message': 'Passwords must match.'
            })
        else:
            try:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
                user.save()
            except IntegrityError:
                return render(request, 'lms/signup.html', {
                    'message': 'Username already taken.'
                })
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        return render(request, 'lms/signup.html')
```

When I submit the form, I get this error:

```
OperationalError at /signup
no such table: lms_user
```

I've already done the migrations command. I also deleted tried deleting migrations and pycache folder's content and db.sqlite3 file and did the migrations again but that didn't help either.

Comment: Your registration page seems to be pretty basic and can use the default and recommended django views. Find out more here - https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html

Comment: Have you executed `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate`?

Comment: @SUTerliakov Yes, I did.